# Javascript Copy Text

Tags: javascript, onclick, copy-paste

I want the user to be able to click a button and have certain text copied to the clipboard. I have the following code:

```
<script>
  function funcCopyXtraCode(XtraCode)
  {
    XtraCode.execCommand("Copy");
  }
</script>

<button onclick="funcCopyXtraCode('test1')">Copy</button>
<button onclick="funcCopyXtraCode('test2')">Copy</button>
```

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: what's the issue ? and have you googled for it ?

Comment: Sorry, I got busy and haven't gotten back to this question. Does anyone know how to get this to work on an iPhone? I swear my sample worked on the iPhone when I wrote it, but it doesn't seem to now.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in few ways.

Without using a plugin, here is a simple example:

```
try {
    var copyToClipboard = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = copyToClipboard ? 'ok' : 'not ok';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, something went wrong');
}
```

Using a plugin:
Just use clipboard.js:
https://clipboardjs.com

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Its a security risk to allow web broser to modifying the clipboard. So new browsers don't allow it mostly. You can use **execCommand("Copy")** for this purpose but I think *it will not work with some version of Safari and other browsers*.

```
function selectMe(obj) {
    obj.focus();
    obj.select();
    if (!document.execCommand) return;
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

Then use it like this:-

```
<input value="SelectMe" onclick="selectMe(this)" name="test" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking it in the link below.It's very straight forward  [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that page. I was wondering if it was possible to not use an input box and just send the text I want copied to my javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

One way or another, you will need a input type of text, to copy the text;

I have hidden the input to give a neat effect;

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = copyText;

function copyText(e) {
  let buttonText = document.getElementById('button');
  let inputBox = document.getElementById('target');
  console.log('buttonText.innerHTML',buttonText.innerHTML)
  inputBox.setAttribute('value', buttonText.innerHTML);
  inputBox.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  
  alert(inputBox.getAttribute('value')+' is now in ur clipboard');
}
```

```css
#target {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button text="Button 1" id="button">Button 1</button>
<input type="text" id="target">
```

Comment: So there is no way to just send the text that I want copied to a Javascript function?

Comment: As far as I have seen, NO. But I could always be wrong. Pls research further and let me know if u find otherwise.

Comment: When I paste your code, it doesn't paste the text that should be copied.

Comment: I have fixed the bug. pls give it a try now.